# Reorder/replace in responsive layout without changing HTML only CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I know it's much to read but I hope anybody takes the time to help me. Thanks!!!

This is a pice of my code from my responsive website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media (max-width:1227px) and (min-width:769px) {
html    {
    background-color:rgba(228, 40, 40, 0.66);
}
#navigation_ul_left {
    padding-left:7px;
    padding-right:4px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
main    {
    margin-left:210px;
}
nav {
    width:200px;
    min-height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:white;
}
#book_cover {
    width:100%;
}
#book_informations  {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#book_left  {
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    display:table-header-group;
}
#book_middle    {
    margin-right:20px;
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    display:table-footer-group;
}
#book_right {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding:5px;
    display:table-row-group;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navigation">
<ul id="navigation_ul_left">

<li class="li_navigation_left">Test1</li><br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test2</li><br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test3</li><br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test4</li><br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test5</li><br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test6</li><br>

</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<div id="book_informations">
<div id="book_left">
<img id="book_cover" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">

<p>Test123ABC</p>
<p>Test456DEF</p>
<p>Test789GHI</p>
</div>

<div id="book_middle">
<p id="book_title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p id="book_discription">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div id="book_right">
<div id="payment_div">

<p id="chose_payment">Das ist mein <a href="">Test-Text</a>.</p></div>

</div>
</div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is for the layout between 769px and 1227px. Within this dimensions I want the layout look like this:

[image: This is my target-layout!]

The left "column" in the main (excluding the navigation on the left side) should be fixed size, ca. 250 px. The right "column" (the big Lorem-ipsum-placeholder-text) should be variable (perhaps width in %) and fill the space between left "column" and right browser border.

The problem is, I'll have to do it without changing the HTML code. I only can change the CSS code.

I tried this with `display:table;, display:table-row-group;`… But that doesn't work.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What should happen to the middle column in the screenshot?

Comment: @mm759 The middle column is what I mean as "left" column in the main.

Comment: you want to right column to show in below left column so do not use other right section , and mobile version will work in media

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is @Media ruling in your css in order to maintain both resolutions and to make sure that your html will adapt depending on what resolution the user is using.

Answer (score 0):

please check this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<style>

html {
    background-color: rgba(228, 40, 40, 0.66);
}

#navigation_ul_left {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

#book_informations {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#book_left {
    margin-right: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    display: table-header-group;
}

main {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 230px;
}

#book_cover {
    width: 100%;
}

#book_middle {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    display: table-footer-group;
}

#book_right {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: table-row-group;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #book_middle {
        margin-left: 2%;

    }
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navigation">
<ul id="navigation_ul_left">

<li class="li_navigation_left">Test1</li>
<br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test2</li>
<br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test3</li>
<br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test4</li>
<br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test5</li>
<br>
<li class="li_navigation_left">Test6</li>
<br>

</ul>
</nav>
<main>
 <div id="book_informations">
<div id="book_left">
    <img id="book_cover" src="200.jpg">

    <p>Test123ABC</p>

    <p>Test456DEF</p>

    <p>Test789GHI</p>

    <div id="book_right">
        <div id="payment_div">
            <p id="chose_payment">Das ist mein <a href="">Test-Text</a>.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="book_middle">
    <p id="book_title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <p id="book_discription">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
        fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
        id est laborum.</p>
</div>


</div>
</main>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks good but I need the content in `book_middle` to fill the space between the right browser end and the divs on the left side. Can you fix that, please? I already tried but didn't get it work.

Comment: when you browse if it is not (max-width: 1227px) and (min-width: 769px) then no css use this page so use some other css for out of this and if width is match this then it will work , otherwise other css will work

Comment: please check now, it will work all device , if any problem then just inform me

Comment: Almost perfect. But I need the navigation on the left (white div) with fixed width, ca. 200px. What to do?

Comment: Thanks, working. What if I need the left column `book_right` and `book_middle` with fixed size, too?

Comment: you can do that as like left column and then if need media css as like i did , but if you want responsive then % is best

Comment: Hey @Shafiqul Islam, I updated my CSS code with your solution but I have the problem, that `book_right` is too width. I copied my code here: https://codeshare.io/arnnEa. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please check your code, you used media like  @media (max-width: 1227px) and (min-width: 769px) {
....................
................
} so you screen resolution not match  then this css not work

Comment: I know that, it's just a piece of my code. But within 769px and 1227px it looks like this: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=f2846d-1482916504.png. `#book_right` is too long and not below `#book_left`.

Comment: you use right div section and width 100% so it will be show bellow left and middle column , if you want to show exact bellow in left column then cut right column and put it in left column, no need right section cause you want to show it in left section

Comment: I still don't really understand. In the code example you gave me it's working fine. `#book_right` is below `#book_left`. Why doesn't it work in my code? I cannot find what is different.

Comment: cut <div id="book_right">
                <div id="payment_div">

                    <p id="chose_payment">This is a placeholder!</p></div>
            </div>

and put in bellow <p>SomethingDDD</p>
<p>SomethingDDD</p>

            <div id="book_right">
                <div id="payment_div">

                    <p id="chose_payment">This is a placeholder!</p></div>
            </div>

Comment: My problem is I cannot change the HTML, only the CSS code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131679/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-user7128548).

Comment: Did you make changes in the HTML in your answer code?